# Laravel yajra datatable: cannot retrieve the search parameter from ajax call in controller

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I am trying to build a dataTable with custom filtering with the help of yajra datatable  from [here](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/fluent/custom-filter) :

**HTML table in view :**

```
  <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" method="POST" role="form" action="#">


      <select id="batch" name="batch">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="22">Skill Level CBE Dec 2018</option>
        <option value="2">Batch 2</option>

      </select>

      <button class="btn  btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>

  </form>

     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered datatable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                                    <thead>

                                        <tr>



                                            <th>{{ getPhrase('S/N')}}</th>

                                            <th>{{ getPhrase('Batch')}}</th>
                                            <th>{{ getPhrase('Course')}}</th>
                                            <th>{{ getPhrase('Subject')}}</th>

                                            <th>{{ getPhrase('title')}}</th>

                                            <th>{{ getPhrase('otq_marks')}}</th>
                                            <th>{{ getPhrase('cr_marks')}}</th>

                                            <th>{{ getPhrase('total')}}</th>
                                            <th>{{ getPhrase('average')}}</th>




                                        </tr>

                                    </thead>



         </table>


        @section('footer_scripts')



         @include('common.datatables', array('route'=>URL_STUDENT_EXAM_GETATTEMPTS.$user->slug, 'route_as_url' => 'TRUE'))


        @stop
```

As to `common.datatables`, `datatables.blade.php` has :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

     tableObj = $('.datatable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
                retrieve :true,
            // cache: true,
            type: 'GET',

            ajax: {
             url: '{{ $routeValue }}',
             data: function (d) {
                 d.batch = $('#batch').val();

             }
         }



     });


    $('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        tableObj.draw();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

**ajax url value $routeValue refers to `URL_STUDENT_EXAM_GETATTEMPTS` constant (to be clarified later) used in view  in whatever way.**

When I select a value from the `"batch"` drop-down and press the `submit` button, an ajax call is made to the route. In browser inspection tool, I see that a lot of query parameters are added in the ajax URL and our `batch` param is also there. Now I need to retrieve that `batch` parameter inside the controller.

**Now about the server side code :**

The constant   `URL_STUDENT_EXAM_GETATTEMPTS` used in blade has the value `PREFIX.'exams/student/get-exam-attempts/'`

And in `route.php`, the route is defined as :

```
Route::get('exams/student/get-exam-attempts/{user_slug}/{exam_slug?}', 'StudentQuizController@getExamAttemptsData');
```

In controller I have :

```
public function getExamAttemptsData(Request $request,$slug, $exam_slug = '')
    {

    //body goes here 

    }
```

I have  used all the following methods to get the `batch` parameter in the controller but in vain :

```
$request->get('batch')
$request->query('batch')
Input::get('batch')
```

How can I retrieve the value of `batch` inside the controller ?

**EDIT:** BTW I am  using `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` for the `Request $request` variable in controller function parameter

**EDIT2:**  The browser inspection tool shows the ajax request url as :

http:// localhost/lcbs/exams/student/get-exam-attempts/myuser123 ?draw=2&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0......search%5Bregex%5D=false&**batch=22**&_=1541684388689.

So you see that `batch` is there in the query parameters.
 But inside the controller,  the code `$request->getQueryString()` only shows
 `%2Fexams%2Fstudent%2Fget-exam-attempts%2Fmyuser123`

And `\URL::current()` shows http:// localhost/lcbs/exams/student/get-exam-attempts/myuser123

That means, the `$request` misses the complete query string.

**EDIT3:**   @ Adrian Hernandez-Lopez, I am pasting the FULL content of Kernel.php here :

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,

    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

        'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
        'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
        'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
       // 'adminOrGuest' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminOrGuestMiddleware::class,

    ];
}
```

Comment: What happens, when you check the $_GET['batch'] superglobal in your controller?

I know, that this is not the best solution, but you should check this just for debugging.

Comment: @ISTI, empty output

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ? in the Route is not used to define an optional parameter but a string instead:

```
Route::get('exams/student/get-exam-attempts/{user_slug}/{exam_slug?}', 'StudentQuizController@getExamAttemptsData');
```

Could you please change it and see what you get?

```
Route::get('exams/student/get-exam-attempts/{user_slug}/{exam_slug}', 'StudentQuizController@getExamAttemptsData');
```

Also, the query string you posted has a space after `myyser123`, this could also explain the issue.

```
http:// localhost/lcbs/exams/student/get-exam-attempts/myuser123 ?draw=2&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0......search%5Bregex%5D=false&batch=22&_=1541684388689.
```

So I would suggest to check how the value is defined in the javascript code

```
url: '{{ $routeValue }}',
```

Comment: `exam_slug` is an optional parameter, so no way to make it mandatory. As to the space after myuser123, I added it intentionally while writing in SO so that the link just becomes text without being any actual link because the link points to localhost not any online site.

Comment: Can you check that there is no redirect that may be redirecting? Do the other get parameters, drag, columns,.... appear in the Request object?

Comment: if redirection would be there, then the yajra table would not display. Other parameters are also unavailable. But I found that with `\Request::getRequestUri();`, I can get the whole url except the 'localhost' part. From then I can `explode` the url string by using `&` as the delimiter and get all params in an array and from that array I can look for whether a certain param (i.e. 'batch') is there and can use that.

Comment: Does ```$request->input('batch')``` also return empty? And also, what output do you get from ```$request->all();```?

Comment: `$request->input('batch')` is empty and `var_dump($request->all());` gives `array(1) {
  ["/exams/student/get-exam-attempts/myuser123"]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

Comment: That's interesting. So the request uri is converted entirely into a request parameter. I'd suggest to check the middlewares and also to debug the $_GET values before the controller, for example to check the values in the first middleware called in the request.

Comment: How do I check the values in the first middleware called in the request?

Comment: In ```Kernel.php``` you may have a ```$middleware``` array with those middlewares called in every request; and you can check your routes files to find more middlewares called. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware for more info

Comment: I added 'EDIT3' to show the full content of `Kernel.php`. Do you find any middle-ware there that intercepts the HTTP request to change incoming parameters ?